# I'm having a mismatch error when calling Round() in an SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, rounding

I have a simple Access 2007 database and when I run any of those sql queries

```
SELECT Round(CDbl(15.243),2)
```

Or

```
SELECT Round(15.243,2)
```

I'm having a type mismatch error in the criteria expression

This also doesn't work

```
SELECT Round(15,0)
```

Do you have any clue?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I can't reproduce this. That likely means you have some VBA somewhere that redeclared the `Round` function, which is a major bad practice, but not enforced or checked.

Comment: Note that redeclaring `Round` specifically is something that some devs tend to do, since `Round` in Access/VBA uses banker's rounding, which results in different results than normal rounding, and this often causes confusion because people rarely expect it. It's still a major bad practice imo because it causes unexpected behaviour for people expecting to use the normal round function.